# Rails 5 Scheduling App Find all shifts for a user

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

We are attempting to create an endpoint that allows for a user to view all of their personal shifts across all calendars.  Currently I have the following syntax in the shifts controller:

```
def myschedule
    @user = current_user
    if @user
        @shifts = Shift.where("end_time > ?", Time.current).order("start_time ASC").limit(100)
        render "/shifts/index2.json", status: :ok
    else
        render json: ('You do not have access to these shifts'), status: :unauthorized
    end
end
```

This as expected is returning the first 100 shifts across all calendars, but for **all users**.  What would be the best direction to search for a way to limit the shifts to just the ones for a specified user.  I would appreciate some guidance in the right direction.  The json rendered is an array of hashes.

As far as relations go on the model level:

a shift has_many users, through usershifts
a user has_many shifts, through usershifts
both user and shift has_many usershifts
and usershift belongs_to both user and shift.

I attempted:

```
def myschedule
    @user = current_user
    if @user
        @shifts = Shift.where("end_time > ?", Time.current).order("start_time ASC").limit(100).include?(@user)
        render "/shifts/index2.json", status: :ok
    else
        render json: ('You do not have access to these shifts'), status: :unauthorized
    end
end
```

Which returned undefined method map for false: Falseclass in my json view.

Here is the json view as well:

```
json.shifts @shifts do |shift|
json.shift_id shift.id
json.start_time shift.start_time
json.end_time shift.end_time
json.calendar_name shift.calendar.name
end
```

I also tried to throw a .joins(@user) to the end of @shifts, that returned an unknown class User for the json.

Also I attempted:

```
def myschedule
    if current_user
        @shifts = Shift.where("end_time > ?", Time.current).order("start_time ASC").limit(100).where(:user_id => params[:user_id])
        render "/shifts/index2.json", status: :ok
    else
        render json: ('You do not have access to these shifts'), status: :unauthorized
    end
end
```

which gave the following error in server log

```
ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column 
shifts.user_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...ERE (end_time > '2018-10-13 14:52:02.693352') AND "shifts"."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What would be the best direction to search for a way to limit the
>   shifts to just the ones for a specified user

This should work

```
@shifts = @user.shifts.where("end_time > ?", Time.current).order("start_time ASC").limit(100)
```

Comment: WOW I can't believe I didn't try this.  Thank you!